# Modifying data written to disk by Ext4 filesystem

Tags: c, linux-kernel, cryptography, filesystems, ext4

I'm working on the academic project, part of which is applying transparent encryption (AES-CTR) to the selected Ext4 files stored on the disk (I can already mark them as encrypted using new ioctl etc.,).

In order to do so, I need to find the best spot to call my algorithm on the data, while it's read or written from/to the device. Due to large amount of features (like journal, inlines, o-direct, extents) provided by the filesystem, I'm struggling for few days now to find the proper solution - I need to operate on the raw data, as it's stored in the datablocks.

I had few ideas in mind, one was to hook in somewhere on the callpath from `sys_read(...)` and `sys_write(...)`, more precisely `ext4_file_write(...)` and `generic_file_aio_read(...)` - but that wouldn't work with `mmap`, and probably is not the way to go. Another approach would be to do it through `ext4_writepages(...)` and `ext4_readpages(...)` (and it's callback, as it's async), when the memory pages are written down to disk.

Because it's not production version, just a proof of concept - I can switch off some Ext4 features in order to simplify the task. While using the algorithm I need to be able to access the inode's xargs (where the key id is stored), and as well be aware of the block number in order to generate the initial vector used in [en/de]cryption. Do you have any ideas and/or suggestions regarding that issue?

Answer (score 3):

There are many alternatives to design the solution for this.

One way could be to use [Wrapfs](http://wrapfs.filesystems.org/) (a stackable filesystem) which will help you intercept the call from VFS to underlying physical file system. You can choose to add your hook before or after the underlying filesystem call is invoked.

Benefits of doing this way would be.
1. Your code can work with any physical filesystem seamlessly.
2. You need not change/modify original filesystem code.
3. You will have completely different module.

So the call hierarchy would look like,
Application <=> VFS <=> Wrapfs <=> Physical FS (ext3/ext4/etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That seems to be a good approach, however I'm not sure if acceptable, as it was rather about modifying Ext4 itself - what obviously make things much more difficult...

Comment: With the approach I have mentioned you need not modify the exiting EXT4 implementation, and that's the cool thing about usage of wrapfs. Please let me know if you need further clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

FUSE ([Filesystems in userspace](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)) is a good alternative because it is easier to implement in user space than in kernel space. You have a wide set of languages to chose from. This approach will be much easier.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be an interesting approach. However the main point was to do it in kernel space, extending ext4 fs, as I've pointed out. It was a part of the Operation System clasess.

Comment: I think Mavla is trying to say you should reconsider changing the specification. If your teacher said he wants you to modify Ext4 it might have been a suggestion, not a requirement. I often had no problem negotiating changes at university.